# Rails - Problem with passing local variables

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm running Rails 6.0.3.2 and I want to render a partial passing a local variable to another controller view:

My routes:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users

  root to: 'notebooks#index'

  resources :notebooks, only: [:index, :new, :show, :create, :edit, :update, :destroy] do 
  # For details on the DSL available within this file, see https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html
    collection do
      get "list"
    end
  end

  resources :tags

end
```

Notebook Model:

```
class Notebook < ApplicationRecord

  has_one_attached :photo
  validates :asin, presence: true, uniqueness: true
  after_initialize :init
  
  acts_as_list column: :position, add_new_at: :bottom

  has_many :taggings
  has_many :tags, through: :taggings

  def init
    self.edited ||= false
  end

end
```

Tag Model

```
class Tag < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :taggings
  has_many :notebooks, through: :taggings
end
```

In Tag controller:

```
  def index
    @tags = Tag.all.order(created_at: :asc)
  end
```

I tried to follow [this guide](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#passing-local-variables) and render the "index view" from Tags Controller on the "list view". The application finds the tags/_index.html file, but return the error **undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass**. Bellow my views code:

In app/views/notebooks/list.html.erb:

```
  <%= render :partial => "tags/index" , locals: {tags: @tags}%>
```

In app/views/tags/_index.html.erb

```
<% tags.each do |tag| %>
  <div>
    <div class="d-flex">
      <p><%= tag.id %></p>
      <p><%= tag.name %></p>
    </div>
    <p>tag.taggings.count</p>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Anyone can point me what i'm doing wrong? I read the Layouts and Rendering in Rails documentation, but i don't have a clue why the instructions won't work on my project...

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The rails  way to do this is just to create a partial for a single record:

```
# app/views/tags/_tag.html.erb
<div>
  <div class="d-flex">
    <p><%= tag.id %></p>
    <p><%= tag.name %></p>
  </div>
  <p>tag.taggings.count</p>
</div>
```

You can then pass the collection to render and Rails will look up the partial and render it for each member in the collection:

```
<%= render @tags %>
```

This is short for:

```
<%= render partial: 'tag', collection: @tags %>
```

See [Rendering Collections](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#rendering-collections).

Comment: Of course you also need to ensure that @tags is not nil. The error is probably due to slop - the code is in the wrong controller or you've fallen victim to the common misconception that render will call the method on the other controller.

Comment: Also note that the place to populate ``@tags`` in @Yuri's case is in ``NotebooksController#list``, not in ``TagsController``. The question seems to imply a misunderstanding that ``TagsController#index`` is somehow tightly coupled and gets called when the partial is rendered in the notebooks view.

Comment: @rmlockerd yeah that was the common misconception is was hinting at. Render just renders views.

Comment: @max Thanks guys! I misconcepted this... I thought that the best practice was to not populate too much one controller, so I was using these two controllers (thinking that render could call a method from another controller). (Sorry for the late response, I was traveling and couldn't acess my computer)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem where a local wasn't showing up in the partial. Here's my code:

```
<%= render "chats/messages", locals: { chat: @chat } %>
```

but it needed to be:

```
<%= render partial: "chats/messages", locals: { chat: @chat } %>
```

Then it worked as expected (the `chat` local variable was available in the partial).